# Why would my local static files not load from the host in a VirtualBox guest?

Tags: localhost, virtual-machine, virtualbox, static-files

I'm trying to get my localhost dev site working in a VirtualBox Windows 10/Edge vm running on an Ubuntu host. The site loads, but only external scripts and CSS files load. Nothing with a relative path will load. *No 404 errors appear in the console*, and I can't click or follow the script links in Edge's dev tools. It's like those files aren't even being requested. I *can* follow external file links and see the code.

File paths are like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dir/file.ext"></script>
```

I have my hosts file set up like so:

```
10.0.2.2    outer
10.0.2.2    localhost
10.0.2.2    127.0.0.1
```

Only the first entry is probably required, but I'm throwing darts at the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must run your web application (in your vm) using ip 0.0.0.0 (not in 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.0.2) on port you want.

Comment: I've tried `10.0.2.2  0.0.0.0` with no luck. Is that what you meant?

Comment: No, just use 0.0.0.0.

Comment: I don't understand. Please revise your answer to explain better.